# How to use C .dll

Tags: c, go, dll

Is there any way to use custom C dll in golang?
I have my dll written in C (goDLL.dll)
and i want to use it inside go

Here is little example what i want to get:

```
package main

    //#import "goDLL.dll"
    //extern void add(int * A, int * B, int * C)
    //{
    //      *C = *A + *B;
    //}
    //
    // import "C"
     import (
     "fmt"
     ) 

func main() {

    var AA *C.int = new(C.int)
    var BB *C.int = new(C.int)
    var CC *C.int = new(C.int)

    *AA = 5
    *BB = 4

    C.add(AA, BB, CC)
    fmt.Println(*CC)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to use custom C dll in golang?

The answer to your question, yes

You have to import the C that you commented in your code. In order to call the c function, you need to import "C".

```
import "C"
```

The cgo way allows you to call the function this way:

```
import ("C")
...
C.yourDllFunc(...)
```

---

Reference and more information about [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Very generic example [cgo](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo).

```
package cgoexample
/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myprint(char* s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

func Example() {
    cs := C.CString("Hello from stdio\n")
    C.myprint(cs)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}
```